# Pandas DataFrame: Assign integer to a new column if fulfilling multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe to then assign an integer value depending on conditional formatting. An example would be:

if ((a > 1) & (a < 5)) give value 10, if ((a >= 5) & (a < 10)) give value 24, if ((a > 10) & (a < 5)) give value 57

where 'a' is another column in the dataframe.

Is there any way to do it with pandas/numpy without creating a function? I tried few different options but none worked.

Comment: Posting an example of your dataframe would help. May have a hard time understanding this.. Is `a` another column in the dataframe? or some random variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [
    2, 3, 5,7,8,10,100]})
pd.cut(df.a,bins=[1,5,10,np.inf],labels=[10,24,57])
Out[282]: 
0    10
1    10
2    10
3    24
4    24
5    24
6    57
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [10 < 24 < 57]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think any way of doing this without creating a function would be pretty roundabout, though it's actually not too bad with a function. Additionally, your conditions don't really mesh with each other, but I assume that's a typo. If your conditions are relatively simple, you can define your function on the fly to keep your code compact:

```
df['new column'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: 10 if x < 5 else 24 if x < 10 else 57)
```

that can get a little hairy if your conditions are more complicatied - it's easier to manage if you define the function more explicitly:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 1 and x < 5: return 10
    elif x >= 5 and x < 10: return 14
    else: return 57

df['new column'] = df['a'].apply(f)
```

if your really want to avoid functions, the best i can think of is creating a new list for your new column, populating it by iterating through your data, and then adding it to your dataframe:

```
newcol = []
for a in df['a'].values:
    if x > 1 and x < 5: newcol.append(10)
    elif x >= 5 and x < 10: newcol.append(24)
    else: newcol.append(57)
df['newcol'] = newcol
```